# Set default config fonts in ckeditor 5

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I have project with ckeditor 5. I try to set default config for family and size font's. In ckeditor 4 we could set default config fonts by

`font_defaultLabel` and `fontSize_defaultLabel`.

So how i can set this same in ckeditor 5 ?

```
 function SetDefaultFont(fontSize) {
        CKEDITOR.config.fontSize_defaultLabel = fontSize;
    }

function SetDefaultFontFamily(fontFamily) {
    CKEDITOR.config.font_defaultLabel = fontFamily;
}
```

Comment: You should check their documentation about migration from 4 to CKEditor 5, https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/font.html

Comment: Thanks @arielb for answer. I know this but how i config 'default' fonts ? I need this to set fonts from database. In example above i have functions which set size and family font's. In parameters i set values from db. But in ckeditor 5 we don't have similar opportunities. Yes we have option like 'default' but where i can manipulate with this ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the answer you're looking for, but I also had a similar problem and found the following solution while searching.

By default, the default font-size is 1em.
Therefore, if you adjust the font-size of the parent element, the font size inside the editor is linked and adjusted.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by setting a css variable and set the variable as your preferred one.

css class:

```css
.ck-editor__editable_inline p
{
  font-size: var(--fontSize) !important;
  font-family: var(--fontFamily) !important;
}
```

and then ngOnInit (I'm using Angular version)

```
 ngOnInit() { 
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--fontSize', '15px');
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--fontFamily', 'Cairo');
 }
```